Getting the foregroundStyle of mark in SwiftUI
I want to build an app and I would like to know how to get the foregroundStyle that swift uses for the marks in Chart, so I can put a text beside the chart saying something like "You spent x amount of money and the category you spent most on was x category, with a foreground color matching the one on the chart (a donut chart), I have this code. Thanks and sorry if I made a spelling mistake English is not my first language.
I tried using the same as the foreground style but it doesn't work because the function is defined for chart values i think, I also tried looking it up online but I didn't find anything
Chart(data) { product in
  SectorMark(
    angle: .value(
      Text(verbatim: product.title),
      animate ? product.ammount: 0
    ),
    innerRadius: .ratio(0.618),
    angularInset: 2
  )
  .cornerRadius(5)
  .foregroundStyle(
    by: .value(
      Text(verbatim: product.title),
      product.title
    )
  )
}


ChartProxy provides a method that gives you the foreground color, given a plottable value - foregroundStyle(for:). Since this requires a ChartProxy, you would need to put your text in chartOverlay or chartBackground.
Here is a complete example:
struct Product: Hashable {
    let title: String
    let amount: Int
}

let products = [
    Product(title: "Product A", amount: 1),
    Product(title: "Product B", amount: 2),
    Product(title: "Product C", amount: 3),
    Product(title: "Product D", amount: 4),
]

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Chart(products, id: \.title) { product in
            SectorMark(
                angle: .value("Amount", product.amount),
                innerRadius: .ratio(0.618),
                angularInset: 2
            )
            .foregroundStyle(by: .value("Title", product.title))
        }
        .chartPlotStyle {
            $0
                .frame(height: 200)
                .padding(.bottom, 40)
        }
        .chartLegend(position: .top, alignment: .center)
        .chartOverlay(alignment: .bottom) { proxy in
            if let mostAbundantProduct = products.max(by: { $0.amount < $1.amount }),
               let foregroundStyle = proxy.foregroundStyle(for: mostAbundantProduct.title) {
                Text("The most abundant product is \(mostAbundantProduct.title)")
                    .foregroundStyle(foregroundStyle)
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
}

I added the text "The most abundant product is ..." at the bottom of the chart. This might intersect the chart legend or the chart itself, so I moved the legend to the top of the chart using .chartLegend, and also added some bottom padding in chartPlotStyle.
Output:


Note that the colors that are automatically generated for drawing the chart might not be suitable for text. It might have very little contrast with the background of the text, for example. If the number of sectors (i.e. the number of different products) is known at compile time, I would recommend picking your own colors for each product:
let productColors: [String: Color] = [
    "Product A": Color.red,
    "Product B": Color.green,
    "Product C": Color.blue,
    "Product D": Color.purple,
]

Then you can apply these colors to the chart using chartForegroundStyleScale.
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Chart(products, id: \.title) { product in
                SectorMark(
                    angle: .value("Amount", product.amount),
                    innerRadius: .ratio(0.618),
                    angularInset: 2
                )
                .foregroundStyle(by: .value("Title", product.title))
            }
            .chartForegroundStyleScale {
                productColors[$0] ?? .clear
            }
            .chartPlotStyle {
                $0.frame(height: 200)
            }
            .padding()
            
            if let mostAbundantProduct = products.max(by: { $0.amount < $1.amount }) {
                Text("The most abundant product is \(mostAbundantProduct.title)")
                    .foregroundStyle(productColors[mostAbundantProduct.title] ?? .clear)
            }
        }
    }
}


Thank you, how can I do the same thing but the text is a not an overlay? Like a different view in an HStack or something like that? I tried a @State variable but it didn't work im not sure where to change it to the new color. Thanks again

@SantiOch then you’d have to use the second approach. Manually give colors to each sector. Then you can access the dictionary anywhere you want. In my example I put the text as a sibling of the chart in a VStack.
